# UI Table Reuse Cell Constraints Looks Fine in IB But Doesn't Work When Simulated

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

I am having an issue with my table reuse cell where I an unable to style it as some constraints don't seem to apply. In the IB I have applied a constraint to a stack view so it is 40 left from the superview (as seen 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHgiA.png).

Anyway it displays fine in the IB, there are no warnings or anything and in my code I don't change any of the constraints or layout when populating the stack view.[It displays fine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb45u.png).

When I run it in the simulator though it doesn't display right, completely ignoring the left constraint as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaNJn.png) where the time is directly up against the side.

As I said earlier in my code to populate the table view I simply add text to the labels and change the background colour of the cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seem like your stackview's width is fixed, and it only get the trailing constraint. Can you recheck it by set the background color of the stackview

Comment: When I set the background colour to red nothing seemed to happen?

Comment: What do you mean nothing happen? It can't be fix your issue, it only may help you detect error

Comment: I mean when i set the background colour to red it didn't seem to apply, the stack view in the IB file looked exactly the same. The background colour didn't apply (it was still white)?

Comment: You can set background for stack view's super view

Comment: When I do that it works fine (background color goes red for the whole cell - https://imgur.com/a/Y7CYmUT

Comment: Can you post your simulator's screen after set background to red (not xcode's one)

Comment: Nothing changed - https://imgur.com/a/8Pol08w

Comment: In my case (ios 11.4, iphone 8 simulator), every thing is ok. https://imgur.com/a/6sGLzWI

Comment: You can try it by create a new view and tested it. I think the IB's constraint is not a problem

Comment: Thanks Quoc, Ill give it a go and see if that works.